# Openbox Syntax Error in ~/.config/openbox/rc.xml

Tags: fedora, files, configuration, openbox, xml

[image: Openbox Syntax Error]

I added a new keybinding to my rc.xml and now I get this message every time I log into Openbox. Also, the right-click menu does not work anymore either.

Now I would have fixed the error myself, but unfortunately my rc.xml does not have a line 749. It ends at 748.
And I am a bit puzzled at how to "see stdout".

This is what I added, copied from the Arch Linux Wiki.

```
<!-- Keybindings for screenshots -->
  <keybind key="Print">
    <action name="Execute">
      <startupnotify>
      <command>sh -c "import -window root ~/Pictures/$(date '+%Y%m%d-%H%M%S').png"</command>
    </action>
  </keybind>
```

And I changed the quote at the top, which usually says that the document should be copied or else it will be overwritten.

My OS is Fedora 21, I used raw Openbox, right now I am in Gnome.

Comment: Have you diffed that version of the file with the (backup) from before editing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close the `<startupnotify>` tag with a corresponding `</startupnotify>`.

See the [official documentation](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Actions#Startup_notification).

Comment: Oh heck, that's not even supposed to be there... Thanks for pointing it out...

Comment: Everything is alright again, now the strange "line 749" thing makes sense as well, as the open tag reaches till the end of the file. At least I thing that's why.

Comment: @Merlin That's correct: XML is pretty unforgiving in that regard...